# elastic search identify similar documents without search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, spring-data-elasticsearch

Assume I have the below six records in elastic search  ( *id , text* )

```
REC-001 , " Car was damaged"
REC-002 , " Car was damaged on the front "
REC-003 , " My Car got damaged while I was travelling"
REC-004 , " I visited Boulder last week "
REC-005 , " The movie was very scary"
REC-006 , " Your new car looks good"
```

Each of these records would be analyzed and stored as tokens in Elastic Search .

In this set of records , I need to find similar statements . I dont want to fire any search query .

In this example , the tokens for first three records are almost matching ( Car , damaged ) . Two words are common between the first two records ( Car and Damaged )

I want to retrieve those records which share similar tokens.

Is this feasible in elastic search ?

Or if there is any API to retrieve maximum repeating tokens in all documents within a given  index , I can retrieve the top n tokens and fire a search using those tokens.